# Redirecting with simple php and post

Tags: php, html, post, header

I looked through stackoverflow but I could only find sql stuff. How can I make a generic password and username holder to be checked by the php if it has been set, then to redirect to another page? For example if the post contains "Username" for the username part and "Password" for the password part, it will redirect to page in the header when the submit button is clicked.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  Username:<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength = "15"/>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength = "15"/>
    <input type='image' alt='Submit' src='button.jpg' width='15%'/>
</form>`

if ($_POST["username"] == "Username" && $_POST['password']=="Password")
{
 header("thesite");
}
```

Comment: … `header('Location: some/page.php')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good.  It just lacks the `Location:` in the header

```
<?php

if($_POST['username'] == 'Username' && $_POST['password'] == 'Password')
    header('Location: thesite.url');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the "Location :" when reading about headers.

Answer (score 0):

For redirection in HTTP there is the `Location` header. You missed type the name of the header `Location` and the `:`. Change the line to:

```
header("Location: http://thesite.com/...");
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I wasn't aware of the Location tag, and now I see that its on php.net.